# Neural Network code works in console app but not in a WPF app

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, neural-network

I used model to connect to database , which has emails to process them and make them input to Neural Network , The Output Of NN Is great on consol but bad on wpf , in other words , The  probability of tested message bigger than 0.8556546 when the email is spam  and probability  of ham is less than 0.005465465
***When i useed*** The same code On Wpf The Results were ambiguous ; in the other words, the NN gives different probability  on the same message for each training ;e.g : The  probability of spam  tested message 0.25654654 , 0.9999 and , 0.45654564654, 0.5564654654 ; the same results for ham tested message ;
at last i added consol to solution  as project to run code on it , and be referenced by wpf project to display results on wpf ,

**Note:**  The code is the same for both Wpf and Consol 
*Thank you*

Comment: is this a question? where's the questionmark?

Comment: I am sorry this my first question , Why results are good in Consol But Not At Wpf although I used The Same Code On both ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the weights are the same when you load it in the Console app and the WPF app? How are you storing the weights?

Comment: After training the Network I serialize The Network , and Deserialize It at testing

Comment: after training the network , the first Test gives great , for example : after traing if i test net on spam , it gives that this is spam but it results all messages **sapm**  ,
AND When i test the net on ham after training as first test it gives ham ,  but it results all messages **ham**   , i tried to free objects that didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

There is no good reason why this would be.

So something happened when you ran the tests. If it is the same assembly that you are using the differences might be caused by differences between test sets, operating systems, .NET platform versions or other external influences (in general the tester or programmer)

Comment: Thank you For Your Answer , But i test The same Data On both projects , And i used same .NET platform versions for three projects :dll , consol , wpf

Comment: I am so sorry but you didn't. Either the code is flawed or the tests are not equal.

Comment: after training the network , the first Test gives great , for example : after traing if i test net on spam , it gives that this is spam but it results all messages sapm , AND When i test the net on ham after training as first test it gives ham , but it results all messages ham , i tried to free objects that didn't work .

Comment: What do you expect me to say?